# Using sinon.js spy() to wrap an existing function

Tags: javascript, sinon

I'm new to JavaScript testing and have run across a problem when trying to use sinon.js to spy on existing functions.

Let's say I have a function called

```
nsClientInfectionControlIndex.handleEditButton();
```

which looks like

```
var nsClientInfectionControlIndex = {

showQtipError : function (message)
{
    ///<summary>Shows qTip error on edit button</summary>
    ///<param name="message">The text message to be displayed</param>
    $( "#editBtn" ).qtip( nsCBS.ErrorTip( message  ) ).qtip( "show" );
},

goToEditPage : function (id)
{
    ///     <summary>Navigates browser window to edit page</summary>
    ///     <param name="id">The data-id (Client Infection Control Id) attribute from selected row</param>
    var url = '/ClientInfectionControl/ClientInfectionControl/'
    window.location.href = url + "?id=" + id;
},

handleEditButton: function () {
    var id = $( ".selectedRow" ).attr( "data-id" );
    if ( id != null ) {
        nsClientInfectionControlIndex.goToEditPage( id );
    } else {
        nsClientInfectionControlIndex.showQtipError( "Please select a Client Infection Control Note first." );
    }
},

};
```

Now in my test.js I used the following code

```
var errorSpy = sinon.spy( nsClientInfectionControlIndex.showQtipError );

//Act
nsClientInfectionControlIndex.handleEditButton();

//Assert
equal( errorSpy.called, true, "test" );
```

And the test fails (returns a false) although I would expect a true because the nsClientInfectionControlIndex.showQtipError is called.

Although as far as I understand the Sinon documentation I'm spying on my function correctly by including the function in the constructor. http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy

I can get it to work correctly if I approach the spy this way,

```
var errorSpy = sinon.spy();
nsClientInfectionControlIndex.showQtipError = errorSpy;

//Act
nsClientInfectionControlIndex.handleEditButton();

//Assert
equal( errorSpy.called, true, "test" );
```

However this replaces the original method functionality. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this example is a mess. please consider creating something more readable next time.

Answer (score 3):

When spying on object functions you must provide the object and function name separately rather than the actual function. This allows Sinon to replace the real function with the spy.

```
var errorSpy = sinon.spy( nsClientInfectionControlIndex, "showQtipError" );
```

**Warning:** If any code stores the function into a variable *before* setting up the spy, it will bypass the spy.

```
// before test runs
var callback = nsClientInfectionControlIndex.showQtipError;

// in test
var errorSpy = ...

// activated by test
callback();  <-- bypasses spy
```